# excel, add multiple conditions to if statement

Tags: vba, excel

[image]
I am trying to have "P9" change based on the following conditions.
Can I do this with one formula or would a macro be better?

> If M9=S9 "COMPLETE"
> If S9=0 "NOT COMPLETE"
>
> If S9 '<' M9 Then add following text (S9 & "-COMPLETE")<sup>(1)</sup>
> If T9 '<' M9 Then add following text (T9 & "-NOT COMPLETE")<sup>(1)</sup>

Would the =SUMIFS formula work for this?

---

<sup>(1)</sup> I would like these two to be formatted one on top of the other (see R9 as an example)

Comment: You can do this with one if statement in a single cell.  For multiple conditions, use AND(), e.g. IF(AND(condA, condB, condC),"true", "false").  SumIfs would also work for this, depending on how the final outcome will be displayed (number versus string).

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Yes it can be done in one formula, make sure your Wrap Text is on for the cell:

```
=IF(M9=S9,"COMPLETE",IF(S9 = 0, "NOT COMPLETE",S9 & "-COMPLETE" & CHAR(10) & T9 & "-NOT COMPLETE"))
```

[image]

Comment: Awesome, thx. Also how could I add the same condition for "T9" to "U9". They wouldn't both be filled in at the same time.

Comment: That is a new question, please treat it as such, deconstruct this formula and try to add it yourself, when you get stuck ask a new question.